# Read Error on Boot but S.M.A.R.T. Data OK

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, ubuntu-gnome, smart

sorry if the question was asked before, searching brought nothing up.

OS: Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Computer: Acer Aspire v5-131-10074g50akk

The Problem:
Most of the times when I want to boot the laptop it just shows the message "Read Error". Sometimes waiting a few hours, sometimes just turning it off and on again, and sometimes opening the PC up and reinserting the cable into the HDD works to make it boot again, but I could not find a consistent pattern.

Thus I assumed that maybe my disk was failing, but instead all parameters in the S.M.A.R.T. show up OK.

I'm thinking that maybe the harddrive could still be at fault, or maybe a loose connection of PC and HDD?
What could be the reasons for my systems behavior, and what steps could I take to test them?

Again, if this question has been posted before please refer me to that thread.

Thanks in advance
gempie

*Edit: I forgot to mention that I sometimes get a message "Read Error", and sometimes the message "No bootable HDD found [or similar]" on boot.

Comment: More than likely it's your hard drive. There's an outside chance that the SATA drive cable could be at fault. Make backups of your important data NOW. You can check your syslog with `grep -i sda /var/log/syslog*`.

Comment: What do you mean when you say the SMART status is OK?  If you mean the big generic "OK/BAD" warning, that isn't saying much.  You need to look at the actual stat numbers to see if any bad sectors are present or such.

Comment: All values are well above the threshold for potential failure, the Reallocated Sectors Count is zero.